# DeleteView not working with Ajax and Bootbox in Django

Tags: python, django, ajax, bootbox

I'm using Bootbox along with Ajax to delete a listing in my app which is calling a DeleteView but after I confirm the deletion, nothing changes.

View.py

```
class FileDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Uploaded
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
    template_name = 'FileManagement/delete_file.html'
```

Script

```
<script>
    $(".delete-file").click(function () {
            var button = $(this);
            var id = button.attr("data-id");
            console.log(id);
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?",
                function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            method: "GET",
                            url: "delete/" + id,
                            success: function(){

                         }
                      });
                    }
                });
        });
</script>
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.FileDelete.as_view(), name="delete_file")
```

I haven't finished the success part but it's still not deleting from the database.

Comment: try to use POST request instead of GET

Comment: If I use POST or DELETE, it says that I'm missing a csrf token. Any idea on how to add it?

Comment: I've fixed this by adding beforeSend to AJAX but not it makes 2 DELETE requests with 301 and 302 codes and that a third DELETE request with a 200 code. The first two have the url for the Delete view but the second doesn't have anything.

Is this okay or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use POST request instead of GET. [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView)

Also, do not forget to include `csrf_token`.

```js
<script>
  $(".delete-file").click(function () {
    var button = $(this);
    var id = button.attr("data-id");
    console.log(id);
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?", function (result) {
        if (result) {
          data = {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
            id: id
          }
          var posting = $.post("{% url 'delete_file' %}", data);
          posting.done(function (data) {
            // done
          });

          posting.fail(function (data) {
            // fail
          });
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this but now whatever button I click, it deletes the listing. Cancel and Confirm both delete it. 

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: @WebCodefy it was a little mess with brackets. Try now.

Comment: It seems that now the Confirm button doesn't work. Do I need to add something to the posting.done function?

Comment: @WebCodefy no. Check if `if(result)` condition works.

Comment: The if is executed but I get this error: Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.):